# How to change the css file of yammer share button

Tags: css, wordpress, yammer

How to change the CSS file of yammer share button? I want to add my own CSS for the alignment for WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell it to use a custom element and then style that element as you wish.

Source: https://developer.yammer.com/docs/share-button

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_social_buttons.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var yammer_options = {
        customButton : true,
        classSelector: 'my-custom-yammer-share-button'
    };

    yam.platform.yammerShare(yammer_options);

</script>
```